# How to hide div content in php for mobile devices?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, mobile, hide

I using wordpress on this project and this is my class code line in my php file:

```
<div class="footer-banner">
```

Thats how I tried to hide from mobile devices but not working and really I dont know why:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {

div.footer-banner { display: none; }

}
```

Comment: Try to use !Important in media query as I did here  @media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
div.footer-banner { display: none !important;  }
}

Comment: Try: `@media (max-width: 960px) { div.footer-banner { display: none; }}` Also verify that there are not rules affecting `.footer-banner` after your `@media` rule.

Comment: To access class name in css file, you must use "." operator. your last two media queries blocks are wrong as you used "#" for div as well as class name.

Comment: Try to show us more of your HTML, the way you have it at the moment (ignoring that you have a lot of wrong css tags in there) should work.

Comment: By the way, a single `@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {}` to wrap all your CSS will do just fine, since they only have the same `max-width` property anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to something like this.

If You have use `Boostrap` then you can use boostrap class `hidden-sm` for hidden `div` in mobile view.

```
@media (max-width: 1199px) {
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .footer-banner{display:none}
}
```

Comment: Wrong .css file I added that code, have to add the upper code into the bootstrap.css...

Answer (score 0):

For mobile devices you need to use media query, because mobile devices will takes width approx between 320px to 480px

```
@media screen and (max-width: 481px) {
.footer-banner { display: none; }
}
```

and remove other media queries.

Thanks

Comment: This really helped just add Andy's advice to add the meta viewport correctly

Answer (score 0):

Do you have set the meta viewport in HTML `<head>` correctly?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```